# Error installing TypeScript on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am creating my first AngularJs project and following a tutorial. At some point I need to install TypeScript and I get the following error:

[image]

In the log I can see that the following is failing:

> 7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/TypeScript 1704ms
>
> 8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for TypeScript@latest 404 Not
> Found: TypeScript@latest
>
> 9 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: TypeScript@latest

I am using the Package Manager Console in VS 2015 in Admin mode. Also I reinstalled NodeJs (v8.9.1) and using NPM (5.5.1). Any thoughts on what's wrong?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall?  Also what is your npmrc registry set to?
http://wil.boayue.com/blog/2013/06/14/using-npm-behind-a-proxy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module name must be in lowercase as `npm` modules no longer allowed to have capital letters in their names.

So instead of doing this

```
npm install -g TypeScript
```

install module as per below command

```
npm install -g typescript
```